# Codeigniter - Table in the database is resetting/flush all the data by itself

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I have developed a customized marketplace using codeigniter (Hero Framework).

It was working fine and we have uploaded approx 950 products (DB: 6000 rows in almost 3 in a tables).

Now the issue is 2 table in the database is resetting/flush all the data by itself.

This was not happening before and now I am unable to figure it out.

**I need some advice/tips/follow that how can I resolve this issue?**

**Also How can I make my system secure in all aspects in codeigniter?**

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can help you?

Comment: Actually that is the problem that I am unable to find out what is the reason because code is working fine.

Comment: I had also tried disabling all the cron jobs that I have setup for daily database backup.

Comment: You said 'before', before when? And just some of your model code would be a start. When is it resetting?

Comment: Before means I think that when products reached to near 1000 products then it reset the db but i am not sure about it

Comment: Check that your sql tables aren't limited to a certain number of rows?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Some model code:

`class Order_model extends CI_Model {
 private $cache;

 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
 }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68807/discussion-between-jhon-and-bakitai).